# Swift: How to set CAShapeLayer() progress value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cashapelayer

I just create an IOS app where I implement a round progress bar with CAShapeLayer().
And know I want to set in each second the progress value to +1 is this posible?
I would just like to create a progress bar like this one that leaps forward a value every second:
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewbRz.png)

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CAShapeLayer` has animatable `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` properties. You can directly set these and they will be animated automatically, or you can control the animation yourself like any other animatable CALayer property:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 1
animation.duration = 1
shape.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

This will fill the progress indicator in 1 second.

For a stroke end animation to work, you can't use a CGPath which is just a circle - you need an arc with a start and an end, like this:

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addArc(
    center: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150),
    radius: 100,
    startAngle: -0.5 * .pi,
    endAngle: 1.5 * .pi,
    clockwise: false
)
```